# Valgrind and ostream operator

Tags: c++, valgrind, ostream

Why is Valgrind showing error in this code?

```
//  const char * constructor
String::String(const char* s) {
  size = 0;
  while(s[size] != '\0')
    ++size;
  capacity = 0;
  str = new char[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    str[i] = s[i];
    if (size > capacity && capacity == 0) {
      ++capacity;
    } else if ((size > capacity && capacity != 0)) {
      capacity *= 2;
    }
  }
}

// overloading the ostream operator
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const String& other) {
  return std::operator<<(os, other.str);
}

// testing
TEST(Iostream, Out) {
  std::stringstream os;
  String s = "lol";
  os << s;
  ASSERT_EQ(os.str(), "lol");
}

// main function for testing
int main() {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Why is strlen showing here if I haven't used it anywhere?

```
==11274== Invalid read of size 1
==11274==    at 0x48425F4: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:469)
==11274==    by 0x49BCBCD: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
```

Comment: You read `s` up until null terminator, but you do not copy null terminator itself. `operator <<` expects a null terminated string.

Comment: If you don't want null terminated data in your `String`, you could use `os.write(other.str, other.size);` in your `operator<<` instead.

Comment: Note that the `capacity` calculation in the constructor is very wrong. Remove the loop and the `if`/`else` and just set `capacity = size;`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  for operator>> can i write std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, String& obj) { is.read(obj.str, obj.size); return is; } ?

Comment: @yash_21 You need to have allocated space for what you read from the `istream`, so if you read up-until `capacity` and then allocate more memory if needed and only then continue reading, yes - but you would probably have a hard time finding the proper delimiter that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is strlen showing here if I haven't used it anywhere?

```
return std::operator<<(os, other.str);
```

This is the same function that is called when you do:

```
void foo(std::ostream& stream, const char * ptr) {
  stream << ptr;
}
```

How else is the stream supposed to know the length of the passed null-terminated string if not via a `strlen()` or something equivalent?

Comment: I thought, in the case of string literals, the `stream <<` would output, character by character, until a nul terminator was reached.  This means that it doesn't need to call `strlen`.  Do you have any proof that `strlen` is called? (just curious)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, yeah, that's definitely an oversimplification, I'll correct the answer

Comment: One technique is to use `strlen` then perform a block write.  I didn't see anything in the standard on how the `operator<<` is required to be implemented.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The question is not about the standard, but about where the strlen() the OP is seeing comes from.